# How to load JSON file and then populate data in select drop down menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, drop-down-menu, jquery-chosen

Hi everyone I have JSON file that I should load and then populate the data. Element that should be populated is drop down menu with `chosen` JQuery library included. I'm wondering if my code is structured correctly since I'm getting any data populated in drop down menu. I see one problem might the race condition between JS and DOM elements. I'm not sure if that is causing the problem or maybe JQuery chosen. If anyone know the best way to load the file and populate data please let me know. Thank you.

```js
var appData = {};
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON("JSON/Buildings.json", function(json) {
    appData.Buildings = json;

    var bldgMenu = $('.bldg-menu');
    bldgMenu.find("option:gt(0)").remove();

    $.each(appData.Buildings, function(key, value) {
      alert(value.NUMBER);
      bldgMenu.append($("<option></option>").val(value.NUMBER).text('(' + value.NUMBER + ') ' + value.NAME));
    });
  });
});

/*Example of my appData JS after JSON file is loaded

var appData = {
  Buildings : [
    {number:"56",name:"Big Grove"},
    {number:"12",name:"Umbrella"}
  ]
}

*/
```

```html
<script language="javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="Chosen/chosen.jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Chosen/chosen.min.css">
<script language="javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="Bootstrap_Confirmation/bootstrap-confirmation.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<form name="frmSave" id="frmSave" class="frm-Submit" autocomplete="off">
  <div class="form-group required">
    <label class="control-label" for="buildings"><span class="label label-primary">Buildings:</span></label>
    <select multiple class="form-control bldg-menu chosen-select" name="frm_bldg" id="frm_bldg" required>
      <option value="">--Choose Building(s)--</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-1 col-lg-1">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Your data has `number` and `name`, not `NUMBER` and `NAME`?

Comment: @LoganB.Lehman Yes, NUMBER and NAME is what my data has.

Comment: It may be good to update that in your first snippet then, because it looked at though the data was lowercased according to that comment

Answer (score 0):

Modified your code a bit to miimic fake AJAX. It populates data in select menu. Let me know if that's not what you are asking and I'll modify answer.

```js
var appData = {};

$(document).ready(function() {
  //$.getJSON("JSON/Buildings.json", function(json) {
  setTimeout(function fakeAjax() {
    var appData = {
      Buildings: [{
          number: "56",
          name: "Big Grove"
        },
        {
          number: "12",
          name: "Umbrella"
        }
      ]
    }

    manipulateDom(appData);
  }, 2000);

  function manipulateDom(appData) {
    var bldgMenu = $('#frm_bldg');
    bldgMenu.find("option").remove();
    appData.Buildings.map(obj => {
      let formattedText = `(${obj.number}) ${obj.name}`;
      bldgMenu.append($("<option></option>").val(obj.number).text(formattedText));
    });
  };

});
```

```css
/* Hi everyone I have JSON file that I should load and then populate the data. Element that should be populated is drop down menu with chosen JQuery library included. I'm wondering if my code is structured correctly since I'm getting any data populated in drop down menu. I see one problem might the race condition between JS and DOM elements. I'm not sure if that is causing the problem or maybe JQuery chosen. If anyone know the best way to load the file and populate data please let me know. Thank you.*/
```

```html
<script language="javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="Chosen/chosen.jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Chosen/chosen.min.css">
<script language="javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="Bootstrap_Confirmation/bootstrap-confirmation.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<form name="frmSave" id="frmSave" class="frm-Submit" autocomplete="off">
  <div class="form-group required">
    <label class="control-label" for="buildings"><span class="label label-primary">Buildings:</span></label>
    <select multiple class="form-control bldg-menu chosen-select" name="frm_bldg" id="frm_bldg" required>
      <option value="">--Choose Building(s)--</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-1 col-lg-1">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```